# My MacBook gets stuck but still has 44 GB of storage left

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive

My MacBook has 125 GB storage space (other 125 GB is for Windows). It still has more than 44 GB available but it gets stuck every two hours. I have tried all the methods I can find and have deleted what I can delete. But it still doesn't work! Now I can't write my final paper in Word!

[image: When it starts up it still has 44 GB available]
When it starts up it still has 44 GB available

[image: Less than 2 hours later it would be like that]
Less than 2 hours later it would be like that

And then all the application paused and I have to re-start.

[image: I've checked my Activity Monitor.]

Comment: When it gets stuck, what is the blue space? If you look in console app, can you see any messages about errors in storage? Are you able to drill down and find out where the space is growing? or is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes every time my Mac starts up the RAM is almost full and the storage would become smaller and smaller. I have no idea where the storage space goes!

Comment: Ram is supposed to be full. Hard drive storage, not so much. If you save your work often, rebooting every few hours will get your paper done. Then you can look in /private/var/vm to see how many swap files exist...

Answer (score 1):

You have  memory leak somewhere and it's causing your system to essentially supplement ram with hard drive.

Open activity monitor, go to the memory tab, and sort by usage. See if you can figure out what program or combination of programs is gobbling up all your memory. 
Also that same tab will show you used memory, swap space, etc.

Comment: Interesting thought. Massive paging out to swap files would explain things.